# python-daemon not logging stdout redirection

Tags: python, stdout, daemon

I am using python-daemon in my code that has print statements in it. I want to send them to a file so I ran the following:

```
python server.py >> log.out
```

However, nothing goes in `log.out`.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us some example code?

Answer (score 6):

The DaemonContext object allows redirecting stdout/stderr/stdin when you create the object. For example:

```
import os
import daemon


if __name__ == '__main__':
    here = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    out = open('checking_print.log', 'w+')

    with daemon.DaemonContext(working_directory=here, stdout=out):
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            print('Counting ... %s' % i)
```

You should be able to `cat checking_print.log` and see the output from the print statements.

A good reference for the DaemonContext object is [PEP 3143](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3143/).

Answer (score 0):

The "problem" is that python-daemon closes **all** file descriptors, including stdout.  You either need to do what @elarson suggested or (if you want to keep the stdout redirection when starting your daemon) exclude sys.stdout from being closed by adding something like

```
files_preserve = [sys.stdout]
```

to you DaemonContext invocation.

Answer (score -1):

if you have an error in your code it will not be written to the file. See http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html

Try creating this file:

```
print 'stdout'
raise Exception('stderr')
```

Answer (score -2):

If it's already running as a daemon you'll most likely need to force redirection of STDOUT, STDERR etc. You can read more on [I/O Redirection here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).

```
python server.py 2>log.out >&2
```