# Linux output redirection daemon does not work

Tags: python, linux, output, daemon

I have a python script like this :

```
while True:
    print("ok")
```

I created a daemon test.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=Un service de test.

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/andy/Desktop/test.py > /home/andy/Desktop/test.log 2>&1

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And I active it with sudo systemctl start test.service.
No log file is created :The output redirection is not working.

When I write systemctl status test.service, I have:

```
● test.service - Un service de test.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-10-18 00:50:29 CEST; 20s ago
 Main PID: 3651 (python3)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/test.service
           └─3651 /usr/bin/python3 /home/andy/Desktop/test.py > /home/andy/Desktop/test.log 2>&1

oct. 18 00:50:29 andy-G551JW systemd[1]: Started Un service de test..
oct. 18 00:50:29 andy-G551JW python3[3651]: ok
oct. 18 00:50:29 andy-G551JW python3[3651]: ok
```

How may I redirect the output in a daemon script ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python-daemon and stdout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146128/python-daemon-and-stdout)

Answer (score 1):

Don't redirect its output. Let the script print to stdout. Systemd will store its output in the systemd journal, which you can view with `journalctl -u test` or `systemctl status test`.

Comment: I have just 2 "ok" with a while True: print("ok"). Is it normal ?